# Is there a way to first sync redux store state between tabs and then let each tab control its own state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new at using redux and I couldn't find anything helpful to solve my dilemma.

I have a react app with a redux store. I have filtering options at the top of the app (some datepickers, etc) and some tabs (Link elements) with different content as the main part of the page.

I would like to be able to open the tabs in new window (by clicking open tab in new window) and sync the state (which consists of the filtering) over to the new window.

Right now I'm achieving this using redux-state-sync, but that only solves the initial load. From there on, I would like each new tab to manage its own state and pass that on when opening in new window one of its tabs.

Is there an obvious way to go about it?

I tried using localStorage, sessionStorage, but that brings me back to the point that I don't have access to each tab's state, only the last updated state.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just add to uri of new window some post option, like localhost:3000/?sync=true
Then in App.js's componentDidMount function parse this argument, and then dispatch synced state (from indexDB for example) to redux. Your reducer should look like this :

case "SyncState":
     return (action.value)
     break

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand how would that solve it? You mean I should pass all the state in the uri? I want to avoid that since the uri may exceed the length limit.

Comment: No, to uri you should pass just option, which says that state sync is required, state should be saved in indexDB (mb in cookies). The flow will be smthg like this :1) first tab saves the state to indexdb 2) it opens new tab with uri option, which require state sync 3) second tab sync the state with data from indexdb

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But what if multiple tabs are open at the same time and the user switches between them? Say opening in new tab from different tabs. The last state stored isn't necessarily the last state for this particular tab. And I don't want to use indexDB unless it's really necessary.

Comment: You can bind some uid to each tab, and get the state from db (I think it's necessary) by this iud, than uri will look smthing like this /?sync=$uidOfParentTab